# Match with grep when pattern contains hyphen "-"

Tags: grep, special-characters

I wrote the following command in order to match $a with $b, but when the value includes "-", then I get an error. How can I avoid that?

```
# a="-Xmx5324m"
# b="-Xmx5324m"
#
#
#  echo "$a"  | grep -Fxc "$b"
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

Comment: Consider changing your command to `grep -Fxc -- "$b" <<< "$a"` to avoid the unnecessary pipe

Comment: By the way, do you really want a regex match, or do you just want to test whether a string is equal to (or is a substring of) another string? In that case, the shell built-ins `[[ ... ]]` or `case` would be a better choice, since you avoid both the idiosyncrasies of `echo` and the child processes.

Comment: whether a string is equal this is my test

Comment: [SO - How can I grep for a string that begins with a dash/hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427913/2072269), [AU - How to use grep to search for a pattern which starts with a hyphen (-)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/500957/158442)

Comment: Another alternative that you shouldn't use that nobody listed : it's possible to escape the dash inside a quoted string so it is understood by `grep` as a literal character rather than the start of an option, i.e. `echo test-test | grep "\-test"` will match rather than complain about an unknown `-t` flag.

Comment: @Muru  the values are typical values from ambari cluster so we cant to nothing about this , some of ambari cluster have "-" before the characters

Comment: @Aaron we cant use "\" because this is variable and each variable can be diff !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Place `--` before your pattern:

```
echo "$a"  | grep -Fxc -- "$b"
```

`--` specifies end of command options for many commands/shell built-ins, after which the remaining arguments are treated as positional arguments.

Answer (score 13):

[Besides of @sebasth's great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388894/72456), you could tell that PATTERN with [`grep's -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)  option to use PATTERN as a pattern (here using the `<<<` `zsh` here-string operator instead of `echo`; see also `printf '%s\n' "$a"` for portability).

```
grep -Fxc -e "$b" <<<"$a"
```

Or all beside of other options.

```
grep -Fxce "$b" <<<"$a"
```

Since your goal is byte-to-byte ***string equality comparison*** use the `[` command instead.

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

Or if `$a` contains `$b`, using the `[[...]]` ksh construct:

```
if [[ $a == *"$b"* ]]
```

Or more portably in all Bourne-like shells:

```
case $a in
  *"$b"*) ...
esac
```

Comment: `==` is not standard for the `[` command; [it's a bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_bar_.3D.3D_.22.24foo.22_.5D).  Use `=` instead.