# How to grep for a pattern that looks like an option?

Tags: grep, options

```
m@m-VirtualBox:~$ man netstat | grep "-t"
grep: invalid option -- 't'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I don't want to pass the `-t` option to `grep`. Instead I want to locate the line(s) of the man page of `netstat` that talk about the `-t` option of netstat if there are any.

I thought that enclosing the `-t` in quotes would be enough to make `grep` interpret it as a pattern and not as an option, but I was mistaken.

How to do what I want to do?

Comment: See also [-e option in command grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435412/e-option-in-command-grep)

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388892/match-with-grep-when-pattern-contains-hyphen

Answer (score 5):

You can signal the end of options with a double dash `--`.

In this case:

```
man netstat | grep -- -t
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you three options:

1. Use `-e` to explicitly mark it as a pattern: `grep -e -t`
2. Use `--` to mark the end of options: `grep -- -t` (Caveat: recognizing `--` as meaning end-of-options is recommend, but not strictly required, by the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), so it might not be completely portable.)
3. Change the pattern so it doesn't look like an option: `grep "[-]t"` (Caveats: here, you *do* want to quote it, so the shell doesn't treat it as a filename wildcard. Also, this won't work for fixed-string searches with `grep -F` or `fgrep`.)